# Downloading all my Dropbox files to my Android

Tags: dropbox

On my Samsung tablet with Android, I installed a Dropbox app. It shows me all my files, but when I try to open a file for the first time, it has to connect to the Internet to download it.

Since usually I don't have an internet connection, I would like to download all files at once, so that they will be available locally. How can I do this?

Comment: How many files do you need to save?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Search for file synchronization apps like [FolderSync Lite](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dk.tacit.android.foldersync.lite) (Google play)

Comment: dropsync works great for a single folder, thanks